# Kernel Illegal Instruction when writing to kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, fpga

I'm making an FPGA System-on-Chip system where I change hardware configuration at runtime with a kernel module. They system uses Linux 2.6 and the LEON3 CPU (SPARC). Some bitfiles work fine but for certain bitfiles I get a "kernel illegal instruction" or "unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address x". I'm pretty sure my hardware is correct as I have tested it with an alternate method and the hardware I'm changing has nothing to do with the CPU. I'm guessing it is a software/kernel module error. This happens after my 14th entry into the kernel module's write method. I'm not sure where to start for debugging. Any help would be appreciated.

```
# cat x > /dev/y
Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 00001000
tsk->{mm,active_mm}->context = 00000045
tsk->{mm,active_mm}->pgd = fc013400
              \|/ ____ \|/
              "@'/ ,. \`@"
              /_| \__/ |_\
                 \__U_/
cat(86): Oops [#1]
PSR: f30000c7 PC: f0089e90 NPC: f0089e94 Y: 00000000    Not tainted
PC: <vfs_write+0xb8/0x148>
%G: 80080000 00001000  00000001 fd000100  00000dae f09c4370  fbca0000 0000fffb
%O: 00001000 00000003  00001000 fe60e5dc  fe60e430 fe60e420  fbca1e80 f0089e80
RPC: <vfs_write+0xa8/0x148>
%L: fbdcad40 00000000  fbca1e78 00000004  fbc0e940 00000000  fbdd2000 f0035784
%I: 00001000 efe07b50  00001000 fbca1f40  00000000 00000000  000007af 000007af
Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Caller[000007af]: 0x7af
Instruction DUMP: d204200c  f602600c  c416e072 <84088001> 03000010  80a08001  02
800018  b2102002  c404201c
Killed
#
```

Kernel module write method:

```
ssize_t icap_write( struct file *filp, char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos) {
unsigned long words, data, *pdata, mem_loc_temp;

pdata = (unsigned long *)buf;
mem_loc_temp = icap_mem_loc;//reset mem_loc_temp

while((pdata < (buf + count)) && (mem_loc_temp < icap_mem_loc+4096)){
        leon_store_reg(mem_loc_temp,*pdata);
        pdata++;
        mem_loc_temp+=4;
    }
}
```

I think this is my problem. pdata is going out of bounds. Is it a viable fix to modify it to:
**--------------Updated Code-------------**

```
unsigned long *pdata;
static int __init icap_init(void) {
...
pdata = (unsigned long *)kmalloc(mem_size*sizeof(char), GFP_KERNEL);
...
}

ssize_t icap_write( struct file *filp, const char *buf,
                  size_t count, loff_t *f_pos) {

int i, cycles, spins;
ssize_t result;

if(count%4 != 0){
    printk(KERN_INFO "ERROR: count = %d is not a multiple of 4. count mod 4 = %u\n Assuming 0 padding for last word. Configuration may not have completed as expected.",count, count%4);
    //return count;
}

result = copy_from_user(pdata, buf, count);
if (result) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "copy_from_user failed, returned: %d\n.", result);
    return -EINVAL; 
}
spins = 0;
while((leon_load_reg(ctrl_mem_loc+8) & 0x10) == 0){//check done
    spins++;//spin on NOT done
}
if (spins > 0)
    printk(KERN_INFO "%d spins\n", spins);

leon_store_reg(ctrl_mem_loc+8, 0);//deassert start

if(count == 4096){
    cycles=min((unsigned long)1024, (unsigned long)mem_size/4);
}else if((count > 0) && (count < 4096)){
    cycles=min(((unsigned long)count+3)/4, (unsigned long)mem_size/4);
}else{
    printk(KERN_INFO "ERROR: count > 4096\n");
    cycles = 0;
}

for(i = 0; i < cycles; i++){
    leon_store_reg(icap_mem_loc+4*i, pdata[i]);
}

leon_store_reg(ctrl_mem_loc, cycles);//set number of samples
leon_store_reg(ctrl_mem_loc+8, 0x1);//set start high

return count;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your fix works?  Because it appears to do the same thing as the original to me - write to -1 entries, then write the last entry...

Comment: Added more code to make it clearer. My memory space is 4096 bytes and I expect buf to have 4096 bytes and count to be 4096. Maybe I should just hardcode it in for now to avoid confusion, since this isn't going to be reused or anything.

Comment: `4K` is a kernel page.  Aren't you suppose to use `copy_from_user`.

Comment: How do I pull an unsigned long out of the char array `*(buf+sizeof(unsigned long)*i)`?

Comment: You may have alignment issues.  `ulong tmp = buf[i*4] | buf[i*4+1] << 8 | buf[i*4+2]<<16 | buf[i*4+3]<<24;`.  Or use `sizeof(unsigned long)` and a macro probably already exists somewhere.

Comment: Re: your first comment. Should I do `copy_from_user(pdata, buf, count);` instead of `pdata = (unsigned long *)buf;`?

Comment: At least in theory that is correct, but I don't think this is your issue.  I am not familiar with *Sparc*, but the crashing op-code is `84088001`.  The kernel is giving you the code at the point of crash.  The kernel Oops messages are very helpful.  You should try to decode them.

Comment: I think the request at virtual address 0x1000 is the problem. I should only be reading up to 0x0FFC.

Comment: That is a `null` pointer?  Are you sure that is correct?  Do you have special memory at `0x0` or where `null` usually is?  That is strange!  I can see a *physical address* at `null`, but not a *virtual* one.

Comment: Updated the code to what I am currently using. I'm not sure what you are asking though. I don't expect to have anything special at 0x0, so maybe my hunch on that was wrong.

Comment: I now get a null pointer dereference, but not everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to put some code up here for us to help you better.

My first guess is you have an array overwrite in your code somewhere and that when you hit the 14th entry, it hits something that the system needs and causes the exception.  If possible, trace your program as it writes out to see if it is writing where it is supposed to.  Different files will be in different locations in memory and if those area are not as system critical, it may explain why they don't crash and this one does.

One interesting thing from your crash dump:

`Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 00001000`

That is 4096 in decimal - the same as the offset in your while loop.  So maybe there is something going on there, but your code doesn't appear to fix it, and may make it worse as there are 2 conditions to watch for in your while loop.

**Update as your code as changed**

Casting `pdata` to a `unsigned long *` may not be safe if the base pointer is not `long` aligned.  Not sure if your system allows unaligned memory access or not so be careful.

`icap_mem_loc` is an unknown type but appears to be a integral value?  if so, treating integral values and pointers is asking for future trouble.

You are comparing an unsigned long pointer with an unsigned char pointer in your while loop - might be safe, but beware of pointer arithmetic here.

Are you compiling this code with warnings enabled?  if not, do so as I'm sure it will be yelling about the above issues...

What happens if `icap_mem_loc` is NULL or 0?  if that is an error condition, you need to handle it - your page request kinda infers that this is a bad condition and you don't have any `ASSERT` or if conditions to handle this.

Finally, `mem_loc_temp+=4;` That `4` - are you sure `long` is `4` bytes in size on your system.  Should be sizeof()'d or better yet, a `longptr++` construst instead to get rid of ambiguity.

Not trying to attack you here, but pointing out every potential point of failure I see so that we can get this issue resolved for you.

Comment: I modified the question. I think I found the problem, but would appreciate feedback.

Comment: No worries, I really appreciate the help. I got rid of most of the warnings now. I'm pretty sure the system does not allow unaligned access. `icap_mem_loc` is an int and set statically. I fixed the `buf + count` by casting it to `unsigned long`, which is checked for size in the initialization method.

Comment: Can you post your updated code for all to see?  And does it still crash?

Comment: I decided to change the format of the code. Am I better off incrementing local variables than multiplying `i` by 4 every iteration?

Comment: What type is ctrl_mem_loc and icap_mem_loc?  If they are 4 byte types, then just increment them or do &icam_mem_loc[i].  Mixing different pointer types still is dangerous.  Also having the "+8" everywhere is begging for an array overwrite.  Better to change the logic so that the offset is not needed.

Comment: They are `unsigned long`'s as that is what `leon_store_reg` requires.

Comment: Aw, so is this an offset into a memory mapped register list or something similiar?  If so, then that 4 should be a constant that makes this obvious.

Comment: I don't remember the exact solution now, but your answer helped me work through the problems in the code. Marked as answer.